# C reallocating to find end of line, but not getting entire line?

Tags: c

I have a function that is finding the number of lines in a text file and returning these lines. I have to dynamically resize the array. However, it is only displaying the last few letters in each line within the buffer when I print it. I'm new to C. This is the main part of the code:

```
char * foo( char **buffer,  FILE * infile )
```

...

```
int buffSizer = 10;
*buffer = calloc( buffSizer, 1);
do { 
  char * result = fgets(*buffer, buffSizer, infile); 
  if (result == NULL){ 
    free(*buffer); 
    return(NULL); 
  } 
  char * ptr = strchr(*buffer, '\n'); 
  if (ptr){ 
    return(*buffer); 
  } 
  buffSiz = buffSizer * 2;
  *buffer = realloc(*buffer, buffSizer); 
} while (1);
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: I doubt you want to use `*buffer` to store the return value of `calloc` or as an argument to `fgets`. Are you sure you don't mean `buffer` instead? What's its declared type?

Comment: I presume he's got a function he's passing a `char **` to to be allocated for the caller.  It would have been nice for the OP to have included his function signature, though.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you need to realloc, you immediately go back and overwrite everything you've read so far.  You need to account for an offset into `*buffer` for charactrers you've already read.

For example, you could add:

```
int offset = 0;
```

Along with the `buffSiz` declaration, and then use it like:

```
char * result = fgets(*buffer + offset, buffSiz - offset, infile);
```

And then when you realloc, add:

```
offset = buffSiz - 1; // -1 to account for null character stored by fgets()
```

Before this line:

```
buffSiz = buffSiz * 2;
```

As a bit of an aside, it's dangerous to reassign `*buffer` at the same time you pass it to `realloc`.  If an error occurs, you'll leak the original allocation and the data will be unrecoverable.  This example is safer:

```
char *tmp = realloc(*buffer, buffSiz);
if (!tmp)
{
    free(*buffer);
    return NULL;
}
*buffer = tmp;
```

Comment: I do this an now nothing happens at all, I don't even get the last few characters of the line like I used to. I'm going to edit my original post to make things clearer.

Comment: @user2030964, sorry - I had an off-by-one bug.  I fixed it in an edit.  I made a test program here and it works fine now, so this answer should be correct, I think.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  I hope everything I said made sense.